# Per Socket network Buffer queues utilization

Tags: networking, solaris, netstat

Is there a way to get a per-socket send and receive Queues utilization on Solaris similar to the way that Linux' `netstat` displays it?

Example on Linux:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19072               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19008               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This one is per interface and I am looking per socket.

Then use just netstat i.e.

```
uname -r
5.10

type netstat
netstat is hashed (/usr/bin/netstat)

netstat
TCP: IPv4
   Local Address        Remote Address    Swind Send-Q Rwind Recv-Q    State
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ------ ----- ------ -----------
localhost.53206      localhost.64711      49152      0 49191      0 TIME_WAIT
host1.ssh            host2.net.16952      32767      0 49640      0 ESTABLISHED
host1.ssh            host3.13515          63712      0 49232      0 ESTABLISHED
localhost.53206      localhost.64712      49152      0 49191      0 TIME_WAIT
...
```

In case you want to relate the ports to process ids, then the opensource lsof utility is also available for Solaris. Alternatively, if losf isn't available, similar functionality should be possible using a script to combine netstat and fuser.

Answer (score 1):

```
# netstat -i
Name Mtu   Net/Dest   Address   Ipkts   Ierrs  Opkts  Oerrs Collis Queue
lo0  8232  loopback   localhost 52559     0    52559    0     0     0
hme0 1500   sys11      sys11    18973     0    30292    0     0     0
```

This has a Queue  column with In/Out packets. Does this meet you needs?

Note: Ran on solaris 10

Comment: No.  This one is per interface and I am looking per socket.